# Android Studio: How to see class hierarchy for gradle dependencies

Tags: android-studio

I have included various dependencies in my build.gradle file. For example:

`dependencies {
 compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
}`

Is there any way to see the class hierarchy that this provides in Android Studio? e.g. the list of packages and classes.

If I include a .jar dependency in my libs folder, I can 'open it up' in the Project view to see what's in there.

Any similar functionality with gradle dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. It's in this directory:

`{yourModuleName}/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/io.reactivex/rxandroid/1.0.1/jars/`

You can see it easily if you have the Project view open (AS defaults to Android view)

[image]

Comment: In Android Studio 4.2.2 I don't see an exploded-aar folder